# Solution for solenoid valve with can give flow without power? or any other alternative way of it?

Tags: solenoid, prototyping, mechanical, solenoid-valve, flow-control

I want to use a Solenoid valve for my project, the valve will be used for water in which is facing one problem if there is no power, how can we get water from the valve, I don't want to add any kind of batteries in the project. wants to do it mechanically can someone suggest me some solutions for it?
If there is an alternative I can use for the flow purpose, which can give us water with power and without power

Comment: You could install a manual valve in parallel with the solenoid valve.

Comment: if I'm using a two valve at the same time, so the flow input won't be effected by the manual valve,  I have to add some more mechanics for the project, the flow speed can also be decreased

Comment: google for "solenoid valve manual override"

Comment: use a normally open valve.

Comment: Yeah I'm searching for a normal one, still doing research on different types and companies, Thank you @dandavis

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this that's rated for whatever flow you need:

https://www.ebay.com/i/271982596560?chn=ps&dispItem=1

The blue knob at the back is a pull that allows the valve to manually actuate. You can also place an AC or DC coil over the valve to energize it electrically from a micro/plc/etc.

Comment: it's really hard things doing it for more than 100 projects. Thank you @biggidvs

Comment: What do you mean by that?  If this option doesn't work let me know! Also if it does work, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: I already have sold the project to someone and  order for 100 more, I don't want to do anything which is not done professional

Comment: How is using a valve with a manual override not done professionally?  These are commonly used all over hydraulic industries. If you're worried about "professionalism" go with a good brand such as sun: http://www.sunhydraulics.com/about/highlights/twist-and-lock-manual-override-solenoid-cartridges

Size one properly for your project and you're good to go. No power? Twist the valve...it's that easy.